# How to put this Json Data into a Php Variable?

Tags: php, html, json

I´m having problems with json, I don´t get why my code doesn´t work. I want to put the `[secondary_text] => United Kingdom` into a php variable, but I´m getting this Notice all the time:

> **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'predictions' of non-object in
>   C:.........\CCPSeven.php on line 153

**My Code:**

```
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $htmlj = file_get_html('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?key=*****&input=London&language=en',false);
    $jsondecode2 = json_decode($htmlj);
        foreach ($jsondecode2 as $jsonforeach2) {
        $Country = ($jsonforeach2->description->structured_formatting->secondary_text);
    }
    print_r($Country);
```

**The Json:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [predictions] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [description] => London, United Kingdom
                    [id] => *****+
                    [matched_substrings] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [length] => 6
                                    [offset] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [place_id] => ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI
                    [reference] => *****
                    [structured_formatting] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [main_text] => London
                            [main_text_matched_substrings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [length] => 6
                                            [offset] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                            [secondary_text] => United Kingdom
                        )
```

Comment: I can't see how you access `predictions` in your code snipped. Could it be the error is somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it a bit simpler to decode the JSON string to a PHP associative array rather than an object:

```
$jsondecode2 = json_decode($htmlj, true);
$Country = $jsondecode2['predictions'][0]['structured_formatting']['secondary_text'];
```

The 2nd option on the `json_decode` function tells it to return an array rather than an object. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

In your sample code, looks like maybe you've missed off the `['predictions']` bit in your foreach loop? Here are two examples for Object and Array style:

```
// Object style
$jsondecode2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($htmlj));
foreach ($jsondecode2->predictions as $jsonforeach2) {
    $Country = $jsonforeach2->structured_formatting->secondary_text;
    print PHP_EOL . "Object style: Country: " . $Country;
}

// Associative array style
$jsondecode2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($htmlj), true);
foreach ($jsondecode2['predictions'] as $jsonforeach2) {
    $Country = $jsonforeach2['structured_formatting']['secondary_text'];
    print PHP_EOL . "Array style: Country: " . $Country;
}
```

Comment: Hard to be sure without seeing the original JSON but I think maybe the foreach loop needs to iterate like this: `foreach ($jsondecode2->predictions as $jsonforeach2) {
    $Country = ($jsonforeach2->description->structured_formatting->secondary_text);
}` - That said, I'd stick with the array method, much simpler if you ask me! :)

Comment: The PHP docs are really good (and not as daunting as you may think!) the page on `foreach` is here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php - It's pretty readable and remember to scroll down to see examples. I've also updated my answer with example foreach loops in Object and Array style, hopefully that helps make it clearer.